# how to apply a function to specific columns in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, apply

I have a simple question.
I am trying to apply a function to 2 columns inside a dataframe but get an error message.
I don't know what I did wrong with my code ?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
data = [(3_000_000,5_000_000,7_000), 
        (2_000_000_000,4_000_000,6_000_000),
        (5_000_000,8_000_000,9_000_000)]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['A','B','C'])


def human_format(num, round_to=1):
    magnitude = 0
    while abs(num) >= 1000:
        magnitude += 1
        num = round(num / 1000.0, round_to)
    return '{:.{}f}{}'.format(num, round_to, ['', 'K', 'M', 'B', 'G'][magnitude])

df[['A','B']] = df[['A','B']].apply(lambda x : human_format(x))
df
```

`ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().`

I tried:

```
df['A'] = df['A'].apply(lambda x : human_format(x))
df['B'] = df['B'].apply(lambda x : human_format(x))
```

and this works. Why ?

I am trying to apply a function to 2 columns of my dataframe but get an error message.

Comment: Do you need the lambda? Why not just use `apply(human_format)`?

Comment: i had an error message `TypeError: bad operand type for abs(): 'str'`in that case

Answer (score 1):

The error happens because the apply() function in pandas DataFrame operates on an entire row or column at a time, not just one item.

If you want to use a function on each item in several columns, you should use applymap(), like this:

```
df[['A','B']] = df[['A','B']].applymap(human_format)
```

Comment: still the same error message `TypeError: bad operand type for abs(): 'str'`

Comment: There is no such error message with the code in your question. You must have a number formatted as a string in whatever code /data you are trying to use.